# Excel: Sum product to calculate frequency for unique values

Tags: excel

I have a below excel table:

```
Date    Text    Outcome
29-Jun-17   YA  1
29-Jun-17   YA  0
29-Jun-17   YA  0
29-Jun-17   YB  1
29-Jun-17   YB  0
29-Jun-17   YB  0
29-Jun-17   YB  0
30-Jun-17   YA  1
01-Jul-17   JS  1
01-Jul-17   JT  1
01-Jul-17   JT  0
01-Jul-17   JT  0
01-Jul-17   JT  0
01-Jul-17   JT  0
```

Note: outcome is the frequency of the unique value. Can be either 1 or 0. 1 if happens once and zero when is more then once. 
I am trying to get the outcome using SUM PRODUCT function in excel. I tried several but the closest I got was this one `=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B=B2), --(C:C=C2))`
Anyone knows how to use excel to get the outcome?

Comment: why not `COUNTIFS` instead?  Or even just a quick Pivot Table? Can you show what the desired output would be with this data?

Comment: your formula is correct assuming the TXT is the unique identifier and you are totally ignoring the date.  if you want just the count for unique text with 1 and then again with zero I would build a table of unique TEXT entries and in the adjacent columns use a header of 1 and 0 for the columns.  Then instead of refering to B2 or C2 I would use $F2 to point at the TXT and say G$1 to point to your header title of 1 or 2.  now provided your formula is in the upper left corner of your fill in portion of the table copy down and right.

Answer (score 2):

To reproduce your outcome column values, you can use the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2;A2;$B$2:B2;B2)=1;1;0)
```